# Magento multiple stores, same installation, 3 checkout, 3 domains, 1 hosting: how to install SSL?

Tags: ssl, magento, e-commerce

I have read about everything about this situation and had very different recommendations and read many differents scenarios from 2007 to 2010. But nothing exactly like my case even here on stackoverflow, so I'm here to ask the real experts. Considering this:

website1.com
    - hosting: simplehelix
    - domain name: simplehelix
    - main magento installation (1.3.2.4)
    - SSL installed
    - paypal PRO (credit card taken directly on this site)

website2.com
    - hosting: none
    - domain name: goddady
    - DNS/nameserver: to simplehelix servers
    - folder called /website2/ that loads magento
    - paypal PRO (credit card taken directly on this site)

website3.com
    - hosting: geohost
    - domain name: geohost
    - DNS/nameserver: to simplehelix servers
    - folder called /website3/ that loads magento
    - paypal PRO (credit card taken directly on this site)

All 3 sites share most of the same products (80%) because they are 3 real physical businesses from the same owner having mostly the same products. They use one Magento admin for products, categories, customers, sales.

QUESTION: Now, in 2011, I'd like to know exactly what is the simplest, easiest, fastest way to have SSL on website2 and website3 so that all our transactions are secured? Can I just buy SSL on godaddy and geohost and install it there on the domain names and it will work even if the DNS is pointing to simplehelix? Do i have to reinstall magento on 2 new hosting plans + ssl and not be able to share same database?

Note:
- we do not want to share carts
- we want people to stay on the respective websites
- we want to use paypal pro
- keep cost down
- please be clear on your steps/description, as this might help many other people more/less technical

Thank you for your help

Joel

Comment: I'm not sure why there is a *hosting*, *domain name* and *dns* entry for each of your websites.  For example, why does website3.com have hosting and Geohost but the DNS points to SimpleHelix?  DNS, in lamen's terms, is telling the web browser where to look for the files, given a domain name, so it tells the web browser where the domain is _hosted_.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I'm not familiar with anything "server" related and SSL and such. Basically, with magento, you can have 3 "stores" with 1 installation. So webstore1 has the hosting with simplehelix + SSL + magento, webstore2 and website3 are domain names bought at godaddy & geohost that have Name Servers set to simplehelix. On simplehelix they are set as "subdomains". At that point I have no clue. But all I know i want to have 3 stores, 3 checkouts with SSL and only one database with magento and 2 "url" are using the hosting of one website to generate content via magento.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you've had different recommendations.  The answer is simple: you'll need to buy an SSL certificate for each of your domains that you want secured.

Sharing a Magento installation, talking about the DNS, etc, is not relevant.

Buy the SSL certificates, get your webhost (it looks like you're using SimpleHelix for hosting all of the websites) to install them all for you, then change the secure URL in the Magento admin for each of your stores (use the dropdown in the configuration area to change the configuration scope from **Global** to each store in turn) to the appropriate URL, presumably `https://www.website{1,2,3}.com` from `http://www.website{1,2,3}.com`.

Easy :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason I'm confused is that they told me they could only have one SSL per hosting account, so I would need 2 more hosting plan to have 3 secured websites. But then this would mean I have to have 3 different magento installations and 3 different databases... Is this right? Or is there a way to install SSL with my current setup? Remember, my setup is "website1.com", "website1.com/website2/" and "website1.com/website3/" **on the server**. So when you type "www.website2.com", it loads the magento installation as indicated in "website1.com/website2/".

Comment: If you had three different hosting packages, then there is no guarantee that they'd on the same server, and they'd have different owners on the folders, so yes, you'd *probably* need different Magento installations.

Comment: Your request is pretty basic, to be honest.  I find it strange that SimpleHelix can't fulfil your request.  Perhaps it's time to move on?

Comment: Well this is what it seems to me. Magento is <i>meant</i> for this, so shouldnt a mangento hosting company make this easy? Anyway, I don't want to leave them because they have outstanding knowledge and customer service. Stuff I've yet to see on my many other hosting. I'll try to fix this with them I guess

Comment: the problem, rock, is that you are using *cheap* magento hosting. get a dedicated plan and it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to think of Magento terminology 'stores' or 'websites' - with 'stores' you can have lots of them on the same SSL, sharing the same checkout. However, if you have built your sites with 'websites' then you cannot have them all go to the same checkout and you will need multiple IP addresses.
It is relatively simple to move your hosting to a VPS that supports more than one IP address, although check before you leap. It is also possible to move your 'stores' to a single 'website' in Magento.

Comment: WRT to multiple SSL certificates on the same IP address, you don't necessarily need a different IP address for each site, but it's not supported by the older browsers, which might be an issue: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/configure-apache-to-support-multiple-ssl-sites-on-a-single-ip-address/987

Comment: ...but from reading the linked article we are not quite there yet. Let's ignore IE6, but IE7/8 on XP is what a lot of people are using, particularly in the office and on netbooks and that doesn't seem to work yet, or ever will work given that XP development is frozen.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that the easiest way to do this was to buy 2 new hosting accounts at my hosting provider and then buy SSL on both and ask them to redirect to the Magento installation. It worked, but it cost 2x hosting account that I do not use at all...